# makeObjectsPerformSelector not working on IOS7.1

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios7.1

i have array of buttons (IBOutletCollections) name "topFriends"..i need to set hidden the all buttons of topFriends(array name).

```
[self.topInFriends makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Actually its working on iOS7...but its not working on iOS 7.1 .

but when i try to enumerate the array like following,then its working for iOS7 and 7.1

```
[self.topInFriends enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        obj.hidden=YES;
    }];
```

Can anyone please tell me why makeObjectsPerformSelector function not working in iOS 7.1 .I am really frustrated to find the issue..please anyone help me..thanks in advance

Comment: `topFriends` and `self.topInFriends`??? BTW it's working on my end

Comment: yes please test it on iOS 7.1 devices .. i dont have issue on iOS 7.1 simulator..i have issue only in 7.1 devices..

Comment: it's working on 7.1 device

Comment: i am really sorry..i forgot to mention that issue is only in iphone 5s(iOS 7.1)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this from the docs of `makeObjectsPerformSelector` and this is the description of the parameter `SEL` in this method

*A selector that identifies the message to send to the objects in the array. The method **must take a single argument of type id**, and must not have the side effect of modifying the receiving array.*

Then I run this line

```
[self.topInFriends makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHidden:)
                                   withObject:@"Fcuked up"];
```

It hides the button, So it doesn't matter what you are passing. And it makes sense too as your method expect a `BOOL` and you are giving an object to it, I don't know the exact internal implementation of `makeObjectsPerformSelector` but I can conclude some points

When you pass some object say `@"abc"` or `@YES` and when `makeObjectsPerformSelector` invokes your `setHidden` then it's passing object, which obviously has some address too,  to `setHidden` and it converts your object(address) into `BOOL`.
Suppose your addresses are

```
@"Fcuked up" ---> 0x7cde450034798976  (assuming 64 bit pointer)
@YES         ---> 0x7cde450000000000
```

For first case the value of `BOOL` will become true as it's LSB are non-zero and for second case the `BOOL` will become false as LSB are zeros.

#### In whole you should respect apple docs and you should not call a method which doesn't take parameter as `id`

<sup>All thoughts appearing in this answer are mine. Any resemblance to other persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.</sup>

Comment: thanks Inder for your comments..i understood your comments..but i want to know what is the solution to hide all buttons without using enumeration ?

Comment: I don't think `makeObjectsPerformSelector` is not using enumeration internally. So if you're using it then there is no harm. If you don't want to enumerate again and again, then you can create category of NSArray and create your own `makeObjectsPerformSelector`

Comment: it may be due to reason that pointer in 5s are 64 bit and in others they are 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Use `[self.topInFriends setValue:@YES forKey:@"hidden"];` instead.